# Windows Server - Set specific time zone per user

Tags: windows

I am looking for a way to set a specific timezone for individual windows users for when they login via RDP.

I know you can enable the timezone redirection, but this will use the users local timezone. I want to force a user to a specified time zone.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Each Windows Server can only be set to a single time-zone, not on a per-user basis. So short of timezone redirection there is no way to do this.

Providing a dedicated VM for each user may be an option, but is most likely overkill.